Action of symmetric group on polynomial ring
In Example 1.1 of Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra he writes that the symmetric group $\Sigma = S_r$ acts on the polynomial ring $S = k[x_1, \dots, x_r]$ by
$$\sigma(f)(x_1, \dots, x_r) = f(x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma^{-1}(r)})$$
for $\sigma \in \Sigma$ and $f \in S$. However if I let $\sigma, \tau \in \Sigma$ and $f \in S$, I obtain
$$(\sigma\tau)(f)(x_1, \dots, x_r) = f(x_{\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}(1))}, \dots, x_{\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}(r)})$$
but
$$\sigma(\tau(f))(x_1, \dots, x_r) = f(x_{\sigma^{-1}(\tau^{-1}(1))}, \dots, x_{\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}(r)}).$$
Is there a mistake somewhere?

Does Eisenbud explicitly say left action? If not, try letting $\Sigma$ act on the right instead :)

The distinction between left and right action is equivalent in this case to how you multiply elements of $S_n$: left to right or right to left. Eisenbud seems to be multiplying left to right, so that $\sigma\tau$ acts as $\sigma$ first, then $\tau$.

I remember being confused about this too. The map that Eisenbud defines is indeed not a left action of $S_r$ on $k[x_1,\dots,x_r]$, since as noted in your question,
$$\sigma(\tau(f))(x_1,\dots,x_r)=f\bigl(x_{\sigma^{-1}(\tau^{-1}(1))},\dots,x_{\sigma^{-1}(\tau^{-1}(r))}\bigr) \, .$$
To prove this, let $g=\tau(f)$. Then,
$$
\sigma(g)(x_1,\dots,x_r)=g\bigl(x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma^{-1}(r)}\bigr) \, .
$$
Writing $y_i$ for $x_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}$, we see that
$$
g(y_1,\dots,y_r)=\tau(f)(y_1,\dots,y_r)=f\bigl(y_{\tau^{-1}(1)},\dots,y_{\tau^{-1}(r)}\bigr) \, ,
$$
and since $y_{\tau^{-1}(i)}=x_{\sigma^{-1}(\tau^{-1}(i))}$ for all $i$, the result follows. One way to repair this issue is by instead setting
$$
\sigma(f)(x_1,\dots,x_r)=f(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(r)}) \, .
$$
This defines a left action of $S_r$ on $k[x_1,\dots,x_r]$. Alternatively, we can view Eisenbud's map as a right action on $k[x_1,\dots,x_r]$.
